# Is there a tool to detect Android layout inconsistencies?

Tags: android

I'm fairly new to Android development and what troubles me the most is the ability to write a layout that is totally inconsistent: UI elements are

1. Invisible. In that case it may overlap with the other two, but I would say that this may be caused by incorrect sizing (0 height/width).
2. Misplaced. The element is partially visible for instance, part of it being outside the screen on the left or right.
3. Hidden. Behind one or several other widgets.

I understand that sometimes this is what we want to design the UI.

I was wondering if a tool, such as a linter, would be able to analyse a layout file telling was is obviously wrong.

Any help appreciated.